# Can't Import Large Obj or FBX files into Blender

Tags: import

I am trying to import some relatively large files into blender. 
I've tried both Obj and FBX formats to import a group of objects.
The FBX file is only about 133 mb, but I get a traceback error.
The Obj file fails to load, but both cause blender to "not respond".

I'm using blender 2.78 and windows 10. This is what blender gives me when trying to import the FBX file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2252, in load
    elem_root, version = parse_fbx.parse(filepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 166, in parse
    elem = read_elem(read, tell, use_namedtuple)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 124, in read_elem
    elem_subtree.append(read_elem(read, tell, use_namedtuple))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 124, in read_elem
    elem_subtree.append(read_elem(read, tell, use_namedtuple))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 124, in read_elem
    elem_subtree.append(read_elem(read, tell, use_namedtuple))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 119, in read_elem
    elem_props_data[i] = read_data_dict[data_type](read)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 94, in <lambda>
    b'd'[0]: lambda read: unpack_array(read, data_types.ARRAY_FLOAT64, 8, False),  # array (double)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 73, in unpack_array
    data = zlib.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

Comment: I fear we have not enough info to find out what goes wrong here. It can be that you simply run out of memory. Or that there is something corrupted. Or that there is a incompatibility with the file. Or that Windows 10 is the baddie here. Can you split the file in smaller parts? Does it import fine then?

Comment: Large .obj files might need some time to get imported. How long did you wait after Blender supposedly froze up?

Comment: From my experiance, metaphor_set can be right.Try to give it some time to load.

Comment: Well, he gets a error message. At least with fbx. For the obj file it could really be a time issue. The importer works with Python. And that's slow.